# Search for a String inside all files inside a war

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

Where I work someone had Java project and used Eclipse to export that project into a .war package.

Now I need to search for a string inside all the files that make that .war package. I know that a .war package is just a .zip file, and I have extracted its contents, however, now I have bunch of of .class java files (among images, xmls and other stuff) and I have no idea on how to search strings inside them.

I am a Linux Mint user, so I tried using the "grep -R stringHere ." command without success (I am not an advanced user), this command only searches inside text files.

I also searched and found the [crgrep project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crgrep/) but it is currently bugged and it does not work.

Does anyone know a linux command that can search inside all the contents of a .war package and check if those contents contain a specific string or code sample?

I really need to find a way to search through the content of the .class files. That is my only priority so far. I don't care about images nor about any other type of text files.

It would help a lot. 
Thanks in advance, Pedro.

Comment: grep should work for strings, but not for code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unzip your war like any regular zip and from the root search with

```
find . -name "*.class" -print0 |xargs -0 strings -f |grep -i <your string>
```

Pray that your string got encoded in clear text inside the binaries.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple, you can use something like below.

```
find /path -name "*.*" -exec grep -l "string-to-search"{} \;
```

If you need to search by ignoring case, you can use the `-i` along `-l`.

You can read further [here](http://www.digizol.com/2010/10/linux-find-content-filenames-search.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [jad](http://varaneckas.com/jad/). 
Once installed, the following command should work just fine:

```
find . -name "*.class" | xargs jad -p | grep "your string"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using find command:

```
find mywar.war -name '*.class' -exec strings -f "{}" + | grep "mysearchstringhere"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a java question. 
You can however use `strings` command:

`find . -name "*.class" | xargs strings | grep myString`

It will probably find string that you are looking for. But why are you looking for string in compiled binary file? What kind of string are you expecting to locate? If this is your code why not to search for strings in the source code, i.e. java files?

Answer (score 0):

The .war file do not have the source code within them. You will see compiled .class files. This can't be read or you won't find anything meaningful in them.

From your question, I think you will have to use a decompiler to convert the .class to .java files. I would suggest the following options.

- Cavaj, (no support for WIN 7 + ) .. [here](http://download.cnet.com/Cavaj-Java-Decompiler/3000-2213_4-10071619.html)..
- jad, (my personal favourite).. [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-decompiler-plugin-for-eclipse/)
  The advantage with jad is that it comes with a neat eclipse plug in .. download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/)

So once you have decompiled the .class files, you can use any tools ( like grep ) to search for the string..

Comment: Actually they can also contain java classes. Theoretically they can contain everything, since thats nothing else than a renamed zip package.